# VLC: Playing Two Video Tracks Simultaneously in the Same Window

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have several videos with two video tracks: one of a speaker and the other of the speaker's slides. I'd like to play both tracks side by side simultaneously. I've discovered that if I open the video file, it will play Track 1. I can then go to Video -> Video Track -> Track 2, which opens up the second track in a second window.

From a usability perspective, it's difficult to juggle two separate windows for the same video. Is there a way to play both video tracks in the same window? Ideally, what I would like is something like this:

[image: Two video tracks side by side]

To clarify, Track 2 is a video track, specifically an OBS recording of the podium computer screen while the speaker was speaking. There's a separate camera filming the speaker at the exact same time. The tracks are already synced up in my mkv file. I just want to play both at once in one window, not two.

I would appreciate any insight the community can provide. Thanks!

Comment: I want the same behavior you do but I could live with the behavior you describe as what you get.  However, I donʼt have that.  Instead, when I select a different track, it *switches* to that so I only get one at a time.  I think it has something to do with the file format but Iʼm not sure; what format is yours?